# How to run email/sms in landscape iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, modalviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app, which is running only in landscape mode, but recently I wanted to add mail/sms/facebook features (via UIButton actions). The last one is running smoothly, I launch web browser (itself manages portrait mode), but starting mail or sms composer is driving me mad.
I Just want to use this app only in landscape mode, excluding launching mail/sms/fb (browser actually).

I managed to have mail/sms composer in portrait mode when having app screen in landscape, but keyboard appears in landscape too, which is blocking the left/right half of composer - did it with `[composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];`

either I'm reading bad stuff on this topic or I'm simply blind ;) - either way any help needed, thanks

EDIT:

I have a root ViewController with overridden:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

which is returning YES in both landscape modes. This rootVC is firing up ShareVC which has 3 buttons for mail/sms/fb. I wish to acheive something like firing up web browser, which starts in portrait. The same with mail & sms, but using modal view controllers and then returning to ShareVC after sending mail/sms...
I also set orientations in plist to landscape modes. Hope this clarify what I am trying to do :)

Comment: ok, if someone knows how to launch mail/sms composers in landscape mode within landscape app - that would be also satisfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed :)
turned out I was calling present/dismiss modalViewController on a childVC not on rootVC itself, here is code snippet:

```
-(IBAction)goMail{
    NSLog(@"gomail...");
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [picker setSubject:@"Hello iPhone!"];

        // Set up recipients
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"aa@bb.com"];
        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [picker setMessageBody:@"mail content..." isHTML:NO];
        [self.controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        //[picker release];
    }
}
```

Comment: here  is where I've found [solution](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/76670-getting-modal-view-controller-display-landscape-orientation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the desired ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

I don't have a Mac nearby, so there might be error(s).

hope it helps

Comment: but you mean with the snippet I mentioned? or just fire up MFComposers as always with overridden shouldAutoRotate?

Comment: Just copypaste this code to the view controller. It's a default method. So when a user will turn a device it will turn too, but only to a landscape.

Comment: yeah, but when you use landscape app you are not expecting suddenly to change orientation, and I suppose problem is in firing up MFComposers in landscape :/ I will add some additional info in edit in a sec